# How do I create a list object that contains a list of another object type using from within a query using linq and c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to return a list of an object that contains another object list as a databmember using linq.  I've tried the examples shown but I keep getting ad different error with each attempt. One of which is as follows: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SunGard.Tools.Notifications.LinkVariable] ToList[LinkVariable](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SunGard.Tools.Notifications.LinkVariable])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have an object (AlertMessageReturn) that contains some string datamembers as well as a list aof another object (List).  I have a class that defines the LinkVarible and a table that contains the values. My query looks like this:

```
AlertMessagesQuery = from alertMessage in this.context.AlertMessages
where alertMessage.UserId=UserId                                              
select new AlertMessageReturn()
{ PAM_ShortMessage = alertMessage.PAM_ShortMessage,
PAM_LongMessage = alertMessage.PAM_LongMessage,
PAM_LongMessageRemote = alertMessage.PAM_LongMessageRemote,
LinkVariables = (from linkVariable in this.context.AlertMessageLinks
from user in this.context.AlertMessageUsers
 where user.PAMU_PAM_ID == linkVariable.PAML_PAM_ID && user.PAMU_UserId == UserId
 select new LinkVariable()
  {
  Name = linkVariable.PAML_SessionVariableName,
  Value = linkVariable.PAML_SessionVariableValue
   })
};
```

The error is related to the type returned for linkvariables.
Please help.

I changed the code as follows:

```
LinkDataQuery = from linkData in this.context.AlertMessageLinks
   from user1 in this.context.AlertMessageUsers
    where user1.PAMU_PAM_ID == linkData.PAML_PAM_ID && user1.PAMU_UserId == UserId
     select new LinkData
       {
        Name = linkData.PAML_SessionVariableName,
          Value = linkData.PAML_SessionVariableValue
         };
var links = LinkDataQuery.ToList();

    AlertMessagesQuery = from alertMessage in this.context.AlertMessages
where alertMessage.UserId=UserId                                              
select new AlertMessageReturn()
 { PAM_ShortMessage = alertMessage.PAM_ShortMessage,
   PAM_LongMessage = alertMessage.PAM_LongMessage,
   PAM_LongMessageRemote = alertMessage.PAM_LongMessageRemote,
    LinkVariables = links
 };


var AlertMessages = AlertMessagesQuery.ToList();  // this is where the error point to
                        if (AlertMessages.Any())
                        {
                            return AlertMessages;
                        }
```

The error I now get is:System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'SunGard.Tools.Notifications.LinkData'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ to SQL engine cannot turn your sub-query to generate the `LinkVariables` into SQL.  More importantly, SQL cannot return nested data sets like that.

Comment: While SQL Server can't return object graphs, LINQ to SQL can. It takes the flattened rows from SQL and flips them back into the object graph under the covers.

Comment: @JimWooley Only if he wired it up.  It doesn't seem like he has.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you get a message of type 'cannot be translated into a store expression' it is an indicator that you are doing something with your linq that is attempting to be translated into other statements (usually SQL).  For example, if you say

```
....select new MyObject
    {
         Id = Guid.Parse( passedIdentity ),
         ....
    }
```

while this is a totally valid C# statement you will get an error that Guid.Parse cannot be handled by linq.  If it is possible to move the variables into external variables that are used inside the query then it would work.  So you would do...

```
string name = linkVariable.PAML_SessionVariableName;
string nValue = ....
....
select New LinkVariable
{
    Name=name,
    Value=nValue
};
```

Also ... you do not need the closing parens on the Select New statement.

Comment: I separated the queries into 2 and I get back the list of linkvariables but how do I now assign it to the LinkVariables datamember of AlertMessageQuery from within the query?

Comment: You can't do it from within the query, if the query is being sent to the database.  It must work purely in memory.

Comment: How would I be able to assign a list of linkData objects resulting from a linquery to the AlertMessageReturn object while creating the object within the linq Query.  It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

While LINQ to SQL can bring back object heirarchies, it can't project into types that aren't part of the model. Instead of projecting into the AlertMessageReturn type, try projecting into an anonymous type in the IQueryable portion of the code. Once you're done structuring your database query, force the results to come back (using AsEnumerable) and then project that into your AlertMessageReturn type. It's more overhead, but does work. Alternatively, you can use something like AutoMapper to translate your anonymous type into the result types.

```
    AlertMessagesQuery = 
      from alertMessage in this.context.AlertMessages 
      where alertMessage.UserId=UserId                                               
      select new 
      {
         alertMessage.PAM_ShortMessage, 
         alertMessage.PAM_LongMessage, 
         alertMessage.PAM_LongMessageRemote, 
         LinkVariables = from linkVariable in this.context.AlertMessageLinks 
                         from user in this.context.AlertMessageUsers 
                         where user.PAMU_PAM_ID == linkVariable.PAML_PAM_ID && user.PAMU_UserId == UserId 
                         select new  
                         { 
                             Name = linkVariable.PAML_SessionVariableName, 
                             Value = linkVariable.PAML_SessionVariableValue 
                         }) 
      }; 
    var alertMessageResults = 
      from message in AlertMessagesQuery.AsEnumerable()
      select new AlertMessageResult 
      {
        PAM_ShortMessage = mesage.PAM_ShortMessage,
        PAM_LongMessage = message.PAM_LongMessage,
        PAM_LongMessageRemote = message.PAM_LongMessageRemote,
        LinkVariables = (from variable in message.LinkVariables
                        select new LinkVariable { Name=variable.Name, Value = variable.Value})
                        .ToList()
      };
   return alertMessageResults.ToList();
```

Comment: I need to return a List of AlertMessageReturn type List<AlertMessageResult> This creates an Enumerable<AlertMessageReturn>.  I tried assigning a ToList() again but it does not work.